# Access to a specific directory failed with El Capitan and Synology NAS

Tags: macos, nas

After I upgraded my mac to 10.11, access to my download directory on my Synology NAS is denied. Finder said "The origin element of Download can't find". My other Mac on Yosemite, and my Windows 10 PC, can access this directory.

Comment: I've the same problem with El Capitan and Synology

Comment: Not fixed by OSX 10.11.1 update ...